# Error: on branch master - nothing to commit, working tree clean

Tags: git, command-line, controls, version

Every time I type the `git commit -m "inserted name"` command, I get the error: "on branch master - nothing to commit, working tree clean". Even though I initialize the Git `git init` on the working directory and added all the files to the staging area `git add .` I still get this error.
Moreover, even when I use the command `git status`, it shows the same error.

Can someone help me to figure this out?

[image: You can see here the commands:]

Comment: 1. Don't screenshot text. Copy/paste.
2. Had you made any changes to those files since the last commit?

Comment: The command `git status` may be helpful.

Comment: Hi, the problem has been solved.